# Given a number of articles, find which were written by the same author

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis

I have a number of articles, roughly from 1000 to 10000 words each, that have been written by a number of authors. I don't know the author of any article, but I know some authors wrote more than one article.

I want to detect the likelihood, given a pair of articles, that they were written by the same author.

My best guess would be to look for the choice of words and expressions in every article and compute a similarity from that.

I am sure there are more advanced methods that I'm failing to find! Any help?

Comment: Ask Google who the authors were. It probably knows. :p

Comment: That's definitely an approach, but unfortunately it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to do a literature review on "Authorship attribution":
[A Survey of Modern Authorship Attribution Methods](http://www.icsd.aegean.gr/lecturers/stamatatos/papers/survey.pdf) and 
[Authorship Attribution](http://www.mathcs.duq.edu/~juola/papers.d/fnt-aa.pdf)

A [recent research](http://news.yahoo.com/israeli-algorithm-sheds-light-bible-163128454.html) performed an analysis on the authorship of some books in the Bible as well.

Comment: "Authorship attribution" was the search term I needed. JGAAP looks perfect for my needs!